# Android google play services and IntentService

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I want to use the google play service to create an app. My goal is to use the location info even when the app is in background.

I have to create the link with google play service in an intent service or else use sample activity and avoid to stop the connection when app is in background??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is not very clear and you may get better answers if you improve it. Could you provide what have you tried, any code sample etc.? You can also look at [more tips how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a pending intent approach and set your intentService with it, in this way when Android launch the intent your service is started.

Comment: Thanks,it's the approach i was using but i was not sure